# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <:

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I have an opencart shop. Locally, uploading images work without a glitch. Online, it works only if the image is very small. If I upload an image of, say 300kb, the loading gif next to upload keeps spinning and I get the errors:
[image]

**ajaxupload.js:**

```
Line 609: if (response) {
Line 610:    response = eval("(" + response + ")");
Line 611: } else {
Line 612:    response = {};
Line 613: }
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT:
I did console.log(response) and you were right, what came back was the HTML of the 404 page. But how can it be too big? It works if the image is 100kb but doesn't if it's 130kb.

Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: **Don't use `eval`**. Why do you think that you need it?

Comment: I'd guess if the image is too big you're getting a server error response (404) that contains HTML instead of JSON. Do `console.log(response)` or inspect the HTTP request.

Comment: Frits, I didn't write the ajaxupload.js code. It came with opencart. Bergi, I did console.log(response) and you were right, what came back was the HTML of the 404 page. But how can it be too big? It works if the image is 100kb but doesn't if it's 130kb.

Comment: Nothing wrong with eval at all, as long as you are handling trusted input (which is most likely the case with an Uploader handling a server response).  It's also likely your only option if you need to support IE7.  Most people who blindly parrot "don't use eval" haven't the slightest clue what they are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Your Post request is 404ing so the response is not parseable JSON. Looks like your URL has unencoded `/`s in the query variables. Make sure to use `encodeURIComponent()` or some other function to make sure your url is properly escaped

Comment: +1, though slashes do not need to be escaped in query strings

Comment: Then why is it working with small files (100kb or less) and it throws erros with files over 130kb? The files names are pretty much the same (1-130kb.jpg and 1-100kb.jpg).

Comment: i imagine larger files are being sent to a different url? check your console when you send a smaller file and see where the request is being sent and compare it to where it is being sent in the larger files request. 404 error means the file is not found meaning the url you are pointing to doesnt exist.

Comment: @Cris: Your server does handle them differently, so you probably will need to check the responsible PHP code. Any chance it answers with 404 on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

From the error I believe that your response is not a valid JSON.
By the way eval is evil so it's much better to use `JSON.parse`

You can check your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com/

---

Edit: somebody asked why eval is evil so here are some reasons

- it's slower than JSON.parse since it actually starts a compiler
- if not done correctly you can end up with XSS attacks
- it inherits the execution context and the scope in which its invoked

If you need to support old IE versions you also don't need to use eval(). You could use the excellent JSON library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
This will offer you... `JSON.parse` support for old IEs.

Comment: If you need to support IE7, which is likely the case with ajaxupload.js, then eval is pretty much your only option.  Also, as the OP already stated, this is third party code.  Finally, if you are going to suggest someone avoid a specific function, such as eval, you should provide reasons why.

Comment: See my answer then. I replied to both questions: why is eval evil and how you can use JSON.parse with older IEs.

Comment: You do realize that Crockford's JSON libraries use `eval` where JSON.parse is not supported, right?

Comment: Nope. It depends which version you use: there is `json_parse.js` and `json_parse_state.js` too. These versions don't rely on eval(). Furthermore using this library gives you good habits since you will use the right syntax from now on.

Comment: True.  I doubt most people use json_parse.js.  json2.js is most likely the most common JSON object polyfill.  I wonder how much more or less efficient json_parse is, vs json2.js.

Comment: Of course, Crockford's JSON polyfills are a nice option for cross-browser support when client-side JSON-related tasks are required.  My main point is that eval is not always bad, just in some cases.  Here's a great article on the topic by Nicholas Zakas: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Answer (score -1):

Try to rewrite the line just before that error.. (don't copy and paste it).. Works sometimes

Comment: Can you explain why? And no, this syntax error is cause be the `eval` not by the code.

Comment: Wow, just wow. This reminds me of my first year at programming school where i wrote things like `if($test == true){//do nothing}else{//code here}` Programming is a science, you don't have to rely on attempts "because they work sometimes"

Comment: oh.. Good then... I guess there's no point to go further.. And that would the first thing to try if you cant see any obvious reasons..